# Vim (non-gui) background will not go White

Tags: vim

I am trying to set-up a simple vim colorscheme, which is black text on white background.

How do I make the background go White?

Based on [bw.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=335), however I am having a problem getting the background to go white, it goes gray instead.

```
hi Normal         ctermbg=White        ctermfg=Black
```

Gives the same result as:

```
hi Normal         ctermbg=Gray         ctermfg=Black
```

[image]

Although reversing them I can get White text on a black background.

Vim is running in an xterm with t_Co==8, Vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul  4 2011 14:31:51)
```

**Update1**

Using Gnome Terminal 2.16, Which uses a 16 color palette although :

```
tput colors
8
```

The terminal is telling applications it has 8 colors, which is setting t_Co to 8 in Vim.

Vim is using this info and using 'palette entry 8' for White, which in my case was set to a medium Gray. Not sure if the real issue is an incorrect response from tput or the incorrect mapping of White to the palette.

**Update2**

Adding -256color to term makes tput return 256 and makes vim t_Co 256 as well.

For csh:

```
setenv TERM $TERM-256color
```

Originally hesitant to blindly apply 256 color to any system I may be working on, but I think it would be rare to come across a terminal that does not support 256 colors these days. This would also have to be a system/network where I have already set-up my dotfiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your terminal emulator is gnome-terminal, it has a setting for manually modifying the standard 16 colors it supports (gnome-terminal does **not** support 256 colors). go to profile preferences -> colors and update the white color, it may be gray over there.

Comment: Using GNOME Terminal 2.16, Which has a 16 colour palette, t_Co set to 8 by default. White picks up palette entry 8. White is held in palette entry 16 by default.

Comment: My gnome-terminal does support 256 colors?! http://paste.nerv.fi/69030286-gnome-terminal-w-256-colours.png --- I see everyone talks about older versions so maybe not valid. Worth a mention anyway!

Comment: indeed, mine does too, and my version (3.4.1.1) is way more recent than yours :-) I was led to error by another script I ran some while ago that showed me only 16 colors where it shall have shown 256 colors (to prove that the terminal is actually 256 colors).

Comment: BTW, setting environment variable `TERM=$TERM-256color` can help a lot of programs detect correctly the terminal type.

Answer (score 2):

If your terminal emulator supports 256 colors, enable 256 colors in vim:

```
set t_Co=256
```

The background should show up white after issuing

```
:highlight Normal ctermfg=black ctermbg=white
```

Comment: I am trying to set-up colourschemes to fall back to based on t_Co and wanting just a basic black and white version. Might try this though and it will work where possible.